# How to transferOut PDF data from HTML File Input with WebUSB

Tags: javascript, file, pdf, webusb

I've been using WebUSB with Zebra printers for a long time. That works great using TextEncoder. I can't figure out how to get this working with PDF files though.

I've got a Brother printer connected. As far as I can tell, this should work. transferOut expects an arrayBuffer, we can read a file in as an arrayBuffer. However what actually prints is just the binary data onto the page, not the rendered PDF.

Is this not possible?

```js
const input = document.getElementById('fileinput');
const file = input.files[0];
const fr = new FileReader();
fr.onload = async() => {
    await device.transferOut(1, fr.result);
};
fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that Zebra printers natively support receiving and rendering PDF content. These printers understand a language called ZPL, for which Zebra provides reference documentation:

https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/zpl/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf

Comment: Thanks. Yea I'm using a Brother printer for this.

Comment: My apologies for misreading your original question. It looks like Brother label printers support a different control language called ESC/P, and some also support ZPL through emulation. https://support.brother.com/g/s/es/dev/en/command/reference/index.html